# onesignal playerid store to varible (ionic v1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, onesignal

I can console log the player id but fail to store in variable, I want to know that how can I handle it?

```
2018-08-02 12:11:19.246673+0800 [1190:62191] Player ID:undefined
2018-08-02 12:11:19.289098+0800 (Player id)xxxxx-xxxx-xx-xx-xxxx
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  };

  window.plugins.OneSignal
    .startInit("XXXXXXXXX")
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .endInit();
  window['plugins'].OneSignal.getIds((id) => $localStorage.uuid = id.userId);
  console.log("Player ID:" + $localStorage.uuid);
  window['plugins'].OneSignal.getIds((id) => console.log(id.userId));
})
```